# Элементы формы в dll

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

Как использовать элементы формы в методах библиотеки и подключить System.Windows.Forms?
Нужно поместить приведённый ниже метод в библиотеку.

```
       OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
        string filePath = "";
        openFile.ShowDialog();
        filePath = openFile.FileName;
        dataTable.ReadXml(filePath);
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; ++i)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name));
            dataGridView1.Columns[i].DataPropertyName = dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name;
        }
```

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса, конкретизируйте требования, приведите примеры или попытки реализации

Comment: Всё верно, нужно подключить в References библиотеку System.Windows.Forms.dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимые элементы нужно передавать в качестве аргументов метода в создаваемой библиотеке.

```
public void MyMethod(DataTable dataTable, DataGridView dataGridView)
{  
  var openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
  if (openFile.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
  string filePath = openFile.FileName;
  dataTable.ReadXml(filePath);
  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; ++i)
  {
     dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name));
     dataGridView.Columns[i].DataPropertyName = dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Ответ на рисунке:**
а потом
using System.Windows.Forms;

[image: ответ]